# Как проверить словари на одинаковые значения?

Tags: python

Есть список, в котором два списка (либо больше):

```py
{'33610133': {'Id': '33610133', 'Manufacturer': '현대', 'Model': '싼타페 TM', 'Badge': '디젤 2.2 4WD', 'Mileage': 48841}, '33593395': {'Id':'33593395', 'Manufacturer': '현대', 'Model': '싼타페 TM', 'Badge': '디젤 2.2 4WD', 'Mileage': 48841}}
```

Бывают все значения разные, это нормально. Но бывает такое, что значения `Manufacturer`, `Model`, `Badge`, `Mileage` одинаковые (как в примере) и только `Id` разные. Как реализовать в таком случае проверку на совпадение всех значений, кроме `Id`?

Comment: Это не список, в котором два списка, а словарь с двумя элементами, каждый из них словарь со значением словарь.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Например, можно создать промежуточный словарь dl, в котором в качестве ключей - хранить сравниваемые данные для поиска дубликатов, а в качестве значений - хранить список с Id этих данных.

Тогда, дубликатами будут такие Id в dl.values(), если они лежат внутри одного списка, и длина такого списка больше 1. Т.е. может быть несколько различных наборов дубликатов, лежащих в разных списках, которые будут дубликатами между собой внутри одного списка, но не будут дубликатами для других списков.

Например, ниже, два набора дубликатов: три дубликата Id['100', '102', '105'] для Mileage=1, два дубликата Id['101', '104'] для Mileage=2, а для Mileage=3 дубликатов Id['103'] нет, т.к. в dl длина его списка == 1.

```
lst = {
    '100': {'Id': '100', 'Manufacturer': '현대', 'Badge': '디젤 2.2 4WD', 'Mileage': 1},
    '101': {'Id': '101', 'Manufacturer': '현대', 'Badge': '디젤 2.2 4WD', 'Mileage': 2},
    '102': {'Id': '102', 'Manufacturer': '현대', 'Badge': '디젤 2.2 4WD', 'Mileage': 1},
    '103': {'Id': '103', 'Manufacturer': '현대', 'Badge': '디젤 2.2 4WD', 'Mileage': 3},
    '104': {'Id': '104', 'Manufacturer': '현대', 'Badge': '디젤 2.2 4WD', 'Mileage': 2},
    '105': {'Id': '105', 'Manufacturer': '현대', 'Badge': '디젤 2.2 4WD', 'Mileage': 1},
}

val = list(lst.values())
keys = list(val[0].keys() - {'Id'})
dl = {}
for d in val:
    dl.setdefault(tuple(d[k] for k in keys), []).append(d['Id'])

duplicates = [v for k, v in dl.items() if len(v) > 1]
print(duplicates)  # [['100', '102', '105'], ['101', '104']]
```

Answer (score 2):

Чуть другой вариант. Суть:

- делаем словарь с ключом из данных, совпадение которых ищем и значением `Id`
- чтобы данные могли быть ключом, их нужно преобразовать из словаря в кортеж
- используем `defaultdict`, чтобы не думать про инициализацию списков
- в конце выводим элементы словаря, где получилось больше одного `Id`
- внутренний словарь копируем перед выкидыванием `Id`, если нужно сохранить исходные данные как были

```
from collections import defaultdict

data = \
{'33593395': {'Badge': '디젤 2.2 4WD',
              'Id': '33593395',
              'Manufacturer': '현대',
              'Mileage': 48841,
              'Model': '싼타페 TM'},
 '33610133': {'Badge': '디젤 2.2 4WD',
              'Id': '33610133',
              'Manufacturer': '현대',
              'Mileage': 48841,
              'Model': '싼타페 TM'}}

newdata = defaultdict(list)
for k,v in data.items():
    v = v.copy()
    v.pop('Id')
    newdata[tuple(v.items())].append(k)

for k,v in newdata.items():
    if len(v) > 1:
        print(f'{v}: {dict(k)}')
```

Вывод:

```
['33593395', '33610133']: {'Badge': '디젤 2.2 4WD', 'Manufacturer': '현대', 'Mileage': 48841, 'Model': '싼타페 TM'}
```

P.S. Если есть сомнения в порядке следования элементов в словаре, то вероятно придётся усложнить преобразование в кортеж:

```
    newdata[tuple(sorted(tuple(v.items())))].append(k)
```

Comment: Метка python, может python2 имеется виду? Для python2 работать может неверно наверное - tuple(v.items()) разный может быть, , т.к. там порядок в словаре не запоминается вроде, да и в py3 он с какой то там версии сортируемый по умолчанию?

Comment: @vadimvaduxa `Python2` официально не поддерживается и я даже не знаю, где проверить. Наверное, вы правы, по-хорошему нужно наверное сортировать. Добавлю в код, спасибо

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте решить с помощью pandas:

исходный словарь:

```
d ={'33610133': {'Id': '33610133', 'Manufacturer': '현대', 'Model': '싼타페 TM', 'Badge': '디젤 2.2 4WD', 'Mileage': 48841},
    '33593395': {'Id':'33593395', 'Manufacturer': '현대', 'Model': '싼타페 TM', 'Badge': '디젤 2.2 4WD', 'Mileage': 48841},
    '33593396': {'Id':'33593396', 'Manufacturer': '현대', 'Model': '싼타페 TM', 'Badge': '디젤 2.2 4WD', 'Mileage': 48842},
    '33593397': {'Id':'335933797', 'Manufacturer': '현대', 'Model': '싼타페 TM', 'Badge': '디젤 2.2 4WD', 'Mileage': 48843},
    '33593398': {'Id':'335933798', 'Manufacturer': '현대', 'Model': '싼타페 TM', 'Badge': '디젤 2.2 4WD', 'Mileage': 48843},
   }
```

далее просто:

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d, orient="index")
res = df.groupby(["Manufacturer", "Model", "Badge", "Mileage"])["Id"].apply(list).values.tolist()
```

res:

> [['33610133', '33593395'], ['33593396'], ['335933797', '335933798']]

то есть, на выходе вы получите список со списками дублирующихся ключей.

Answer (score 0):

Функция для проверки на совпадение всех значений кроме ID:

```
def check(lst):
    values = list(lst.values())
    first_element = values[0]
    for element in values[1:]:
        for key in element:
            if key != 'Id' and element[key] != first_element[key]:
                return False
    return True
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! А можно уточнить. Я так понимаю функция рассчитана на сверку конкретно двух списков? А если их более двух, например три?

Comment: Можно передать хоть 1000 штук, будет работать

Comment: Нет, работать не будет. Пример, есть три элемента, первый уникальный, остальные два - дубликаты между собой, но не с первым. Соответственно, дубликаты сравнятся с первым, они не равны первому, и вернется False. Более того может быть несколько разных дубликатов, например первый со вторым, и четвертый с седьмым и восьмым, что тут вообще никак не обрабатывается. Да и наверное необходимо выводить Id дубликатов, иначе смысл проверять это.

Comment: Извините, немного неверно понял суть задачи, подумал что все должно между собой совпадать